# Unicode character not rendered in webfont

Tags: css, unicode, webfonts, google-webfonts, glyph

I'm using Google's Noto Sans as a standard webfont. I also want the browser to display special characters like arrows and bullets, using the webfont.

However, Chrome Dev Tools tell me, that e.g. 
the unicode character 'BLACK RIGHT-POINTING TRIANGLE' (U+25B6) http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25b6/index.htm gets rendered as Segoe UI Symbol—Local file(1 glyph) (I'm currently using Windows 10)

*(see screenshot)*

[image]

why is that? Even though I defined Noto as the font for the div, containing the ▶ symbol.

The ▶ symbol is included in the Noto fontset and works perfectly in apps like InDesign, Illustrator etc.

Please see this fiddle: http://codepen.io/lieferant/pen/bZARVV
The corresponding part is `<div class="noto">&#x25b6;</div>`

Comment: You're using `subset=cyrillic,greek` in the font definition.

Comment: Also, you have errors in your html, such as duplicate IDs.

Comment: I corrected those things, but obviously those are not causing the issues!

Answer (score 1):

CSS of font-face Chewy has a unicode-range that didn’t cover the character U+25B6.